# Python - overriding a method based on specific access type

Tags: python, list, ordereddictionary

I have a situation where I need to create a dictionary that keeps track of global order of the values.  I haven't been able to find a good way for the class itself to have an incrementing counter that's also tracked by the value.

Here's what I've written in the meanwhile to get around this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NotMyDict(object):
    """ defaultdict(list) that tracks order globally across the dict.

    Will function as a normal defaultdict(list) unless you modify the
    'ordered' attribute and set it to a non-false evaluating value.  This


    """
    ordered = False
    _data = defaultdict(NotMyDictList)
    _next_index = 0

    class NotMyDictList(list):
        def append(self, value):


    def __repr__(self):
        if self.ordered:
            return repr(self._data)
        else:
            temp = defaultdict(list)
            for key in self._data:
                for value in self._data[key]:
                    temp[key].append(value[0])
            return repr(temp)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if self.ordered:
            return self._data[key]
        else:
            return [val[0] for val in self._data[key]]

    def add_value_to_key(self, key, value):
        self._data[key].append((value, self._next_index))
        self._next_index += 1
```

So I can use this like a normal dictionary for pulling values.  I could have instantiated a list if the key didn't exist, but defaultdict was simple and easy.

Here's an example of the use:

```
test = NotMyDict()

test.add_value_to_key('test', 'hi')
test.add_value_to_key('test', 'there')
test.add_value_to_key('test', 'buddy')

test['test']
Result:
['hi', 'there', 'buddy']
test.ordered = True
test['test']
Result:
[('hi', 0), ('there', 1), ('buddy', 2)]
```

Now - the example of use isn't super important, but the functionality that I can't seem to figure out, is instead of using the .add_value_to_key(), I want to be able to use a normal defaultdict(list) convention of:

```
dict[key].append()
```

and still have it track the index.  Do I need to pass global object locations with id() and reference those objects at a memory level, or is there a way I just don't understand to have a "class global" that's accessible by it's members?

I had also tried to use nested classes, but the nested class didn't have access to the parent class's globals, so I'd have to:

1. Make a list-like class that references the parent class attribute somehow (Maybe with id() and direct memory location reference?)
2. modify/make it's append() function so that it also updates the parent class global counter, and tracks the value with this counter as a metadata field.

I really just can't seem to wrap my head around how to create this object/class in a way that let's me use the same functionality of a defaultdict(list) where I can index/append directly AND have it track the global index order of that new value.

```
dict[key].append(value)
```

Help would be appreciated - I sunk three hours into trying different solutions before I scrapped it and went with the "just use this method to append" for now.

Comment: Ah, for the record, I did troll through questions before I posted this - I kept finding things that just talked about how to instantiate a normal ordereddict(list) or counter.  If there's a "name" for this type of object that I just don't know, hit me with that and I'll be happy to do more research.

Comment: If you have nested classes, its easy to access the parent class's global values by assigning those in the `__init__` method of the nested class.

Comment: Just accessing them wasn't the problem - I can pass a static value with no problem - it was updating the parent's global attribute from the child class that I'm struggling with.  I'm currently toying with idea of passing the child class the memory location of the counter, and then having the child class modify that memory location directly, but it won't be process safe unless I do some pretty heavy modification and add a lot of additional stuff.